# JavaScript round to two decimal places with number 10.435,10.425 is it special case?

Tags: javascript, html, math

Is there any solution for this problem?

I don't want to use if/else.

```
10.435.toFixed(2); => "10.43" //Wrong, should be '10.44'
10.425.toFixed(2); => "10.42" //Wrong, should be '10.43'
10.415.toFixed(2); => "10.42"
10.445.toFixed(2); => "10.45"

parseFloat(10.415).toFixed(2); => "10.42" //Wrong, should be '10.44'
parseFloat(10.425).toFixed(2); => "10.42" //Wrong, should be '10.43'
parseFloat(10.435).toFixed(2); => "10.43"
parseFloat(10.415).toFixed(2); => "10.42"

Math.round(10.435*100)/100 => 10.43 //Wrong, should be '10.44'
Math.round(10.425*100)/100 => 10.42 //Wrong, should be '10.43'
Math.round(10.415*100)/100 => 10.42
Math.round(10.445*100)/100 => 10.45
```

Comment: That is very strange.  Please post your code as text instead of pictures.

Comment: @informaton I edit post change picture to text . Please take a look.Thank

Comment: Thanks for updating your post.  I get similar behavior as well, though not in every case.  I posted a workaround that may help below.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as a workaround for rounding a positive number, `x`, to two decimal places.

```
Math.floor(x*100+0.5)/100);
```

The best reasoning I can find for the behavior between the expected value for rounding is a note (#2) in the [ECMA script standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.round).

Even with 64-bits, it's not possible to represent everything; still, I am a bit surprised by the roundoff error here.

A more general workaround, for positive or negative numbers would be:

```
Math.floor(x*Math.pow(10,2)+Math.sign(x)*0.5)*Math.pow(10,-2));
```

and you can change the `2` to match the number of decimal places you want rounded to.